# How to close serial port while it is still receiving data in c windows form?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, serial-port

How do i close the serial port if it is still receiving data?

I am writing a program that the serial port will always receive data from wireless RF receiver. For wireless RF receiver, it will continuous receiving data.

i wrote :

```
this -> serialPort1 -> ReadLine();
```

to receive data. As continuously receive data from RF module, the read event will always running.

So here, when i want to close port :

```
 this->serialPort1->Close();
```

it come out a problem which is

```
IOException was unhandled
"The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."
```

My request is i can close port without this problem or i can exit it without this problem, i have try to solve for few days but still cant handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating/opening the COM port? Are you using some library for that purpose? If you are using the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, then you could close your port with the [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: It is very risky, lots of things can go wrong.  Deadlock is very common.  In your case the driver falls over and makes a hidden worker thread that raises the events crash.  If you want to support this then *don't* call Close(), leave it up to Windows to close the handle.

Comment: i open the port using this->serialPort1->Open(); then i will to close it, i am using DataReceived event, how can i stop the event and close the port?

Answer (score 1):

You can't be in the function `ReadLine` and the function `Close` at the same time without using threads. Therefore I assume that these calls are in different threads.

The thread that calls `ReadLine` should check an event that indicates that it should stop its operation and indicate that it is idle or completed.

The thread that wants to call `Close` should set the stop event and wait for the idle/complete indication.

Comment: any tutorial for stop the event? I am using DataReceived event to run the receiving part, the wireless keep receiving data and make the read event always running. Any suggestion in making this thread?

Comment: Use `WaitForMultiplyObjects` and wait for both events. This allows to diffentiate between stop and receive. Other functions used: `CreateEvent`, `WaitForSingleObject` (to check the idle indication) `SetEvent`, (`ResetEvent`), `CloseHandle`. There is a good documentation with the functions that should suffice for tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, i will try for it..^^

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (!port.IsOpen)
                return;

               port.ReadLine();

        }
```